# URL rewrite is not working as expected IIS7

Tags: rewrite, url

I am trying to achieve the following rewrite URL in IIS 7:

`subdomain.domain.com/username` should become `subdomain.domain.com/?username`

When I try to match the pattern `/([^/]+)` and test it with `/username`,
it gives me

```
{R:0} /username
{R:1} username
```

and for the rewrite URL I have used `/?{R:1}`

However when I test it in a browser the site throws a `404 error` and does not rewrite the URL.

Please what can I be doing wrong.

Comment: Try `/&amp;{R:1}` in your rule.

Comment: Hi @bjoster, Tried it but still no result. Same 404 error

Comment: Can you please watch the headers in your client (devtools)?